# PHPUnit > How to test whether the correct type was passed to a method?

Tags: php, phpunit

I have a method where I've set the type of first argument to be passed (array):

```
public function create(array $values, $options=array())
{
    // set datetime columns
    if(! isset($values['date_created']) or empty($values['date_created'])) {
        $values['date_created'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    }
    if(! isset($values['date_updated']) or empty($values['date_updated'])) {
        $values['date_updated'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    }

    return parent::create($values);
}
```

How do I test this using PHPUnit, it keeps throwing a fatal error which I guess is to be expected but it doesn't allow my script to run:

```
1) UserTableTest::testCreateMethodWithInvalidArguments
Failed asserting that exception of type "PHPUnit_Framework_Error" matches expected exception "InvalidArgumentException". Message was: "Argument 1 passed to app\models\UserTable::create() must be of the type array, string given, called in /var/www/phpdev/tests/models/UserTableMockTest.php on line 82 and defined" at
#0 /var/www/phpdev/app/models/UserTable.php(16): PHPUnit_Util_ErrorHandler::handleError(4096, 'Argument 1 pass...', '/var/www/phpdev...', 16, Array)
#1 /var/www/phpdev/tests/models/UserTableMockTest.php(82): app\models\UserTable->create('invalid argumen...')
#2 [internal function]: UserTableTest->testCreateMethodWithInvalidArguments()
#3 /var/www/phpdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestCase.php(962): ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs(Object(UserTableTest), Array)
#4 /var/www/phpdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestCase.php(826): PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->runTest()
#5 /var/www/phpdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestResult.php(686): PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->runBare()
#6 /var/www/phpdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestCase.php(760): PHPUnit_Framework_TestResult->run(Object(UserTableTest))
#7 /var/www/phpdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestSuite.php(699): PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->run(Object(PHPUnit_Framework_TestResult))
#8 /var/www/phpdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/TestRunner.php(426): PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->run(Object(PHPUnit_Framework_TestResult))
#9 /var/www/phpdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/Command.php(179): PHPUnit_TextUI_TestRunner->doRun(Object(PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite), Array)
#10 /var/www/phpdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/Command.php(132): PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run(Array, true)
#11 /var/www/phpdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit(55): PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main()
#12 {main}.

FAILURES!                            
Tests: 1, Assertions: 1, Failures: 1.
```

Should I instead remove the type hint and use is_array($values) to tell whether the correct type is passed then throw an exception? In PHPUnit I am expecting an exception is thrown anyway. By the way, below is my test:

```
/**
* @expectedException InvalidArgumentException
*/
public function testCreateMethodWithInvalidArguments()
{
    // pass invalid argument, should be an array of values
    $result = $this->userTable->create('invalid argument type');
}
```

Comment: Either way is fine. Don't overthink unit tests. Personally I'd go with the exception example and if you have an OCD you can `if ( ! is_array($values)) throw new InvalidArgumentException;` but that's kind of a waste of lines of code.

Comment: It seems I have to do `if ( ! is_array($values)) throw new InvalidArgumentException;` for my test to pass, and remove the type hint. Does using the type hint not throw an `InvalidArgumentException`? It seems cleaner to write it using type hinting but my test fails the assertion that way.

Comment: Type hinting [throws a catchable `FatalError`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php) instead of a `InvalidArgumentException`. Don't do `@expectedException Exception`, as it'll catch ANY exception and you will not be testing correctly.

Answer (score 1):

*PHPUnit* just has to be made aware that you are expecting and exception so it can properly handle it and report upon it.

```
public function testExceptionHasRightMessage()
{
    $this->setExpectedException(
      'InvalidArgumentException', 'Right Message'
    );
    throw new InvalidArgumentException('Some Message', 10);
}
```

This was pulled from the *example 2.11* at [PHP Unit Documentation - Writing Unit Tests](http://phpunit.de/manual/4.1/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html)

Comment: Thanks. If I throw the exception from the class using a `if ( ! is_array($values)) throw new InvalidArgumentException;` it passed. I'm guessing that using a type hint (`array $values`) when passing the arguments doesn't throw a `InvalidArgumentException`?

Comment: Yea it seems PHP throws a fatal error for the typed parameters so there is no good way of catching those in your tests since they hault execution. Honestly I would keep the typed array parameter and not worry about unit testing it since its really out of scope. It is a language construct that (hopefully) is covered by its own unit tests in the PHP Core.

Comment: Actually if I just simply set `@expectedException Exception` then it works OK. I just want to ensure that type hinting has been implemented now and in future.

Comment: So, which is the solution to be sure that "now and in the future" the type hint exists in the code? I don't well understand the solutions reported here: i tested them, but they seem not work well.